# Counting Bits in Integers (negative integers?)

Tags: c++, integer, bit, signed

I'm really new to coding (as in started about 1.5 weeks ago), so hopefully, my asking this here isn't too heinous a crime (and if it is, I beg forgiveness).

I'm trying to write a function that counts the bits in an integer and the code I've written seems to work perfectly for counting positive integers, but negative integers seem to act really funny.

From what I had learned, I was under the impression that a negative signed integer just had a bit set out in front of it like the following example:

```
 2:  0000 0010
-2:  1000 0010
```

So ideally my function should act like so: `bit_count([negative number here])` is the same as `1 + bit_counter([absolute value of negative number])`

But it doesn't.

Here's my function:

```
    int bit_count(int byte)
    {
        int bit;
        int tally;
        tally = 0;
        for (bit = 0x80; bit > 0; bit = bit >> 1)
        {
            if ((byte & bit) != 0)
                    ++tally;
        }
        return (tally);
    }
```

Some sample data:

`bit_count(-1)` results in 8
`bit_count(-6)` results in 6
`bit_count(-4)` results in 6

and so on...

I had a friend that I have quite a bit of trust suggest that depending on the machine, there was actually more metadata in front of the signed bit that my bit counting function was including, but I don't know what I'd need to do to correct for that.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the most significant bit usually does represent a negative number when signed, but the rest of them change as well.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: Look up twos complement - flip bits and add one to change from +ve to -ve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, although it is valid to check the most significant bit when determining the sign of an signed integer, the rest of the byte changes as well.

In other words, your code is working correctly, but your premise about the representation of negative integers is wrong.

The mechanism used in signed ints is called two's complement and essentially means taking 2^n, where n is the number of bits, and subtracting the absolute value of the integer to get its negative value.

-2 is therefore

```
1111 1110
```

and not

```
1000 0010
```

as you would expect. The reason for this is that it ensures that standard arithmetical operations work for signed ints.

Comment: ...and then note that it is not guaranteed that the platform you are operating on is actually *using* this encoding (although it is overwhelmingly likely).

Answer (score 0):

After this line: tally = 0; add this for ur expected results as negative numbers are in 2's complement.
if ( byte < 0 ) {tally=1; byte = -1 * byte;}

Answer (score 0):

```
int bit_count(int num)
{
    int count = 0;
        for (unsigned int bit = 1; bit <= num && bit > 0; bit <<= 1){
           if (num & bit){ 
               count++;
           }
        }  
    return count;
}
```

Above answers is also good and working. And alternatively. This snippet worked for me.

I have used unsigned int because it doesn't consider leftmost bit and expected output will be 1 count less.

I like to hear suggestions if any. Thank you and Welcome.

Answer (score -2):

Integer can have a max of 32 bits

```cpp
int n = given(say -25)
int count[32] = {0}; 
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    if ((n >> i) & 1) {
        count[i]++;
    }
}
```

then we can iterate each position.

Comment: The only guarantee given by the language is that `int` is 16 bits wide or more. It need not be a multiple of 8 bits. Also, the code shown does not count the total number of bits set, it counts the number of times a bit *position* is set. All in all, not an improvement over the answer accepted six years ago.